# cordova not available error for google authentication in ionic 3

Tags: angular, cordova, firebase, ionic3

I am doing Google authentication in Ionic 3 using firebase. Its showing a run-time error-

> Cordova not available in browser and plugin_not_installed error in
>   mobile.

Does anyone know how to fix that?

Comment: cordova is not supported with ionic serve.. use emulator or a device.. Also read [mcve]

Comment: Thank you for the help. But I tried in device also, not working.